# how to compare date format

Tags: java, javascript, date, robotium

My application displays dates in different formats based on user settings. I want to test that it displays correct date format. I have the displayed date as a string (2014/12/31). I do not want to verify the actual date, but just the format.

Ex: When user selects yyyy/dd/MM format, it should display it in that format.

Comment: do a round trip test `Date1` -> `format` -> `parse` -> `Date2` and compare Date1 vs Date2.  or are you asking something else?

Comment: I am testing an android application. I have a date string (ex: 21/31/14), I want to automate the test which should say what format it is in out of 4 formats (m/d/y, mm/dd/yy, dd/mm/yy and yyyy/mm/dd)

Comment: thank u, but I was looking for logic to do that

Comment: Please tell me you don't allow yyyy/dd/mm format!!

Comment: For many values, it's impossible to tell if a date is mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy unless you know the date that is being represented. If you know that, it's not hard to do what you ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) **try and parse the String** to the required Date using something like `SimpleDateFormat`

```
 Date date = null;
    boolean checkformat;
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/dd/MM");
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        date = dateFormat.parse("2013/25/09");
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (date == null) {
        checkformat = false;
    } else {
        checkformat = true;
    }

    System.out.println(checkformat);
```

check like above.

2.) **Other approach can be to use regex**, but then you have to inbuilt few supported data format regex in your application, and pick accordingly. Play around the `{2}, {2}, {4}` values inside curly braces to prepare regex.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String input = "2014/12/31";
        boolean checkformat;
        if (input.matches("([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})")) // for yyyy/MM/dd format
            checkformat = true;
        else
            checkformat = false;

        System.out.println(checkformat);
    }
```

more info [here](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.jp/2014/11/validate-date-against-given-date-format.html)

Comment: I tried it, its not working. Test is passing for all date formats. It should fail when I pass a different date format.
  Date date = null;
  try {
   date = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/y").parse(dateString);
  } catch (ParseException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  if (date == null)
   fail();

Comment: The second option is working. Thank you!

Comment: @user3818494 should work now, `dateFormat.setLenient(false);` was missing

Comment: @user3818494 try with firs one, it should be in more controlled by you.

Comment: now the first one works too. thank you! @ankur

Comment: @user3818494 need ur upvote dude. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a custom solution, JavaScript does not have a format date functionality. If you need to handle several formats it could be a hard work and a waste of time.

I recommend use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), a library to manipulate dates easy in JavaScript.

Usage Example:

**HTML**

```
 <script src="moment.js"></script>
```

**JS**

```
var now = moment();
now.format("yyyy/dd/MM");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test for 4 patterns then have 4 simpleDateFormat objects and test each one in turn

If the String does not match then it will throw an exception which can be caught.

Comment: It is not working. The test passes for all different date formats I pass. It should fail when the date is in different format. 
String dateString = (String) ((TextView) myList.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.dateText)).getText();
  
Date date = null;
try {
date = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/y").parse(dateString);
  } catch (ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

if (date == null)
fail();

Answer (score -1):

you can use regex to check your date string format, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String date = "2014/11/01";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{4}/\\d{2}/\\d{2}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(date);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.printf("the date string match format:%s", "yyyy/mm/dd");
    }
}
```